# How to add .NET dll reference to UWP project?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have several .NET dll projects for .NETv4.x. I changed version to 4.6.1 and rebuilded without problems. When I try to add referene to them from my UWP project I get error:

> The project targets '.NETCore' while the file reference targets
>   '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario.

I can't also reference .NET projects from 'Add reference...'->'Projects':

> Unable to add a reference to project

But in project settings I can't see anything to change it's target to '.NETCore'.
Is it possible to reference .NET4.x project from UWP project or convert it to UWP project type?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UWP project can reference Universal Windows Class Library, Portable Library or Windows Runtime Component. Your classic .NET projects are none of those.

If you're planning to continue to develop and use those libraries in both classic .NET projects and UWP, I suggest you try Portable Library in which you can choose target platforms, but beware that this approach can be somewhat limiting because it takes lowest common denominator for available namespaces and classes.

Another approach would be to create two different projects targeting classic .NET and UWP, and share the code between them either adding files as links or using Shared Project. Then resolve all problems with conditional compilation, build them and use appropriate output .dll's for both cases.

Comment: I have this issue. Is there an easy way to change the ..NET classic library to PCL?

Comment: Depends on how many platform-specific code you have. I personally would do that by "brutal force": create a PCL and copy all code in there, then start to eliminate/replace all code which doesn't fit. Maybe there is more efficient way though. There is also .NET Standard came out fairly recently which can be used for same purpose as PCL, but I haven't looked closely into it yet. You can [check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050911/net-standard-net-core-pcl) for more info on it.

Comment: I just created Xamarin.Forms UWP project and was able to add a 3rd party .NET dll library to reference and use it in code.  Note sure in which version of .NET this dll was created as it is not ours but it works.  Also not sure if this was not possible 2 years ago when this question was answered but I am able to do it now