# .NET Standard, .NET Core, PCL

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-core

.NET Standard has been a confusing concept. The idea of a standard .NET library format sounds great. But, it's not clear what it is exactly. There are now .NET Core, and .NET Standard Class Library project templates in Visual Studio, as well as the old PCL projects. I also found that if you go in to the settings for the project, you can switch an existing PCL library over to .NET Standard. It's not clear if  .NET standard is a library? Or a DLL format.

The basic question I'm asking is *which type of library should we be targeting?* I'm mainly doing this for Xamarin projects, but it would be great if we could share these libraries with other platforms, especially .NET Core, and UWP. It's confusing as to why Microsoft brought out two seemingly identical Class Library types at the same time: .NET Core, and .NET Standard.

**Definitions**

*NET Core* - a .NET based runtime environment which conforms to the .NET Standard API definition.

*PCL* - a .NET based library format supported by several runtime environments including .NET, Mono, UWP, and so on

*.NET Standard (Definition 1)* - A set of standard API definitions for .NET based runtime environments

*.NET Standard (Definition 2)* - a .NET based library format supported by several runtime environments including .NET, Mono, UWP, and so on which is a continuation of the PCL format. In Visual Studio, a PCL library can be converted to a .NET Standard library by going in to the properties of the project and editing the target framework.

Comment: read https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/articles/standard/library

Comment: Forget about PCL, as it will soon go away. .NET Standard is a standard, well, so in your case, you should create a .NET Core library which targets a certain .NET Standard, starting from 1.0. Play with it and the concepts will explain themselves.

Comment: I tried this recently. But, what I found was that Xamarin projects won't accept .NET Standard dlls as references.

Comment: This post explains why .NET Standard is still relevant: https://christianfindlay.com/2020/12/21/net-standard/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This from Samuel Englard (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/973#issuecomment-249582799):

> .NET DLLs are formatted according to ECMA-335 (Better known as the
> Common Language Infrastructure). This format is true across all
> platforms we call .NET; Full Framework, Core, Xamarin, Mono,
> Silverlight, etc.
>
> The reason you couldn't use a DLL compiled against one platform with
> another was that the format didn't specify APIs (generally speaking).
> So while they could all read the DLL you'd run into issues of class
> XYZ being in namespace A.B.C on one platform and in namespace D.E.F on
> another, if it existed at all.
>
> PCLs "solved" this by doing two things:
>
> They used Type Forwarding so that even though you wrote your code expecting class XYZ in namespace A.B.C, it could be found on platforms that had it elsewhere.
> It limited what APIs you could use to the lowest common set shared by all the platforms you wanted.
>
> Taking a PCL and converting it to a .NET Standard project is not a
> recompile because of output format but because of the meta data
> included (Type Forwarding particularly).

So, I think that essentially .NET Standard libraries are no different than PCL libraries except for the fact that they put a layer over the top of a different standardized set of APIs, and those APIs may implement different pointers (Type forwarding).

.NET Core is of course a runtime environment, but I think that it is just very closely aligned with .NET Standard. I don't think that it has any special relationship to it other than the fact that it implements the .NET Standard APIs.

**[In my mind, it is generally better to target a .NET Standard Class library because this will be compatible across multiple platforms](https://christianfindlay.com/2020/12/21/net-standard/). If you target .NET Core, this assembly type cannot be referenced in UWP for example. You will see this:**

[image]

**However, if you are working in a pure .NET Core environment, you may find that there are APIs available that are specific to the .NET Core runtime environment, and therefore it will be necessary to target .NET Core directly.**

Please see this glossary:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/glossary.md

Comment: I'd also take a look at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/project-docs/glossary.md to help clear up things better :)

Comment: I've talked to a netfx team member. He said a library based on netstandard will not work on every platform if its code is not able to understand it. For exemple, you can write netstandard code to open a file which will exist on windows, but not on linux. Nuget won't tell you that the package you just installed will not be compatible with - for example - your Xamarin Android project. Nuget will still allow you to add the package as your project does support netstandard too. Which means you can't rely on nuget to check a package's compatibility anymore.  A new world of horror is coming !

Comment: That's why you need to select the correct version of the .NET Standard library to match the platform you are building for.

Answer (score 27):

The documents around this are indeed confusing, but it can roughly be understood as this:

- PCL: libraries that target a set of platform (have the 'least common denominator' of APIs of those platforms). So when writing a PCL you're saying I want to target platform A, B, C
- .NET standard: a 'standard' set of APIs rather than a platform. So basically you don't care about platforms, just the standard (version 1.3, 1.6 ...) and your code will work on all platforms that support it.
- .NET core is not to be confused here, it's 'another version' of the .NET framework. .NET standard will work cross-runtime (.NET framework, .NET core, Mono)

So I guess .NET standard is the way to go :)

Comment: While this makes a lot of sense, it's at odds with the fact that you can actually take a PCL library project, and flick it over to .NET Standard. And, at that point you have to select the .NET Standard version. What really puzzles me is what format am I actually compiling to? I don't even know.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this resource answers most of your questions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

> The .NET Standard Library is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET runtimes. The motivation behind the Standard Library is establishing greater uniformity in the .NET ecosystem.

So as I understand it, the other library types are platform specific and .NET standard is platform agnostic to a point.

If you would like your code available on different platforms then .NET standard seems ideal but pay close attention to which version of the .NET standard that the other platforms support (see table in link).

Hope this helps

Comment: Something that most people don't realize is that .net standard shares the runtime but not the Base class libraries. When you use a .net standard library you pull into your app the System.* dlls that is required by the library. This causes an increase in your deployment size. This is not the case with PCL or full .net dlls.

Answer (score 3):

Standard is for targeting a specific set of API similar to Android API versions. The nuget library is just meta package that contains all libraries that confirms to the standard.

Scott Hunter on MSDEV show has explained this concept very well. Worth checking it out - http://msdevshow.com/2016/07/dot-net-core-with-scott-hunter/