# Referencing .Net class library running under .Net 4.5.x in a UWP app

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I am currently working on a UWP app (which automatically has reference to Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform when I added it). Now I want to reference a class library (contains the models for code reuse) running under .Net Framework 4.5.x into the UWP app but when I try to add the dll it throws this error

" could not be added. The project targets '.NETCore' while file
reference targets '.NETFramework'. This is not a supported scenario."

Is there any work around for this?

Any answers/tips are highly appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37778418/how-to-add-net-dll-reference-to-uwp-project: Your UWP project must reference a Universal Windows Class Library, Portable Library or Windows Runtime Component.

Comment: Which library were you trying to add? There may be a WinRT compatible version.

Answer (score 1):

Because as the error says UWP doesn't support .Net libraries.
Possible solution is to extract and port needed code so you can use it in .Net and UWP projects.
There are several options: [.Net Standart](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/09/26/introducing-net-standard/) or [Portable class library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is highly appreciated. Unfortunately, we have decided to leave the UWP app and have a another alternative for it.